# Select startdate row with daterange between two different dates

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `daterange` which is included in two months.

So I have a dataset of:

```
1   2022-10-01  2022-10-31  
2   2022-11-01  2022-11-30  
3   2022-12-01  2022-12-31  
4   2023-01-01  2023-01-31  
5   2023-02-01  2023-02-28  
6   2023-03-01  2023-03-31  
7   2023-04-01  2023-04-30  
8   2023-05-01  2023-05-31  
9   2023-06-01  2023-06-30  
10  2023-07-01  2023-07-31
```

I have a `daterange` of `startdate` 2023-05-15, `enddate` 2023-06-15.

With this `daterange` I want to get the 8th row which is 2023-05-01 and 2023-05-31. And not the rest of the rows before that. Just one or more depending on the range

I have been trying to achieve this using Linq queries, but with no results.

```cs
var a = new QueryFactory().Period.Where(x => x.Enddate <= request.ReferenceDate);
```

The reason I want row 8 is because that is the "completed month" and the june month is yet to complete if we take the `endDate` as the `referenceDate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to exclude

- rows that start too late i.e. start after your end date
- rows that end too early  i.e. end before your start date

You also want to exclude June as it ends too late.

But it is OK to include records that start before your start date.

If so this becomes

```
l.Where(x =>  (x.Startdate <= end  ) &&  // Excludes rows that start too late
              (x.Enddate   >= start) &&  // Excludes rows that end too early
              (x.Enddate   <= end  )     // Excludes rows that end too late
) ;
```